# google script maximum execution time - return google group emails (huge list)

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to save google groups emails into a spreadsheet but Im getting the 'maximum execution time' error. Any ideas?

```
function listGroupMembers() {
     var GROUP_EMAIL = "prgg@googlegroups.com";
     var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
     var users = group.getUsers();
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Group Mail");

     for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       sheet.appendRow([users[i]]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is probably taking much of the time is the `appendRow()` call.
you should build an array with all the values and write this at once in your sheet.

Code could be like this :

```
function listGroupMembers() {
     var GROUP_EMAIL = "prgg@googlegroups.com";
     var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
     var users = group.getUsers();
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Group Mail");
     var values = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       values.push([users[i]]);
     }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

---

### EDIT

I didn't check the begining of your initial code, `SpreadsheetApp.create("Group Mail");` returns a spreadsheet, not a sheet... that's why it fails on `getRange`.

Since it's not clear what you wanted to get exactly I assumed you wanted to create a new Sheet with that name if it doesn't exist.
The appropriate code would be like this :

```
function listGroupMembers() {
   var GROUP_EMAIL = "prgg@googlegroups.com";
   var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
   var users = group.getUsers();
   if(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Group Mail") == null){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet("Group Mail");
  }else{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Group Mail");
  }  
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    values.push([users[i]]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Serge!
Using your script Im receiving "Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)"

Comment: the error is in your original question, you need to get the sheet:  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Group Mail").getSheets()[0];

Comment: you're right, sorry I didn't pay attenstion to this part of the question... my bad ;)